# Using std::copysign with g++

Tags: c++, c++11, arm, g++

I just figured out some incompatibilities between my tested platforms using std::copysign.

At a first test I try in MSVC to get some algorithms tested. Now I tried to port this c++(11) code to the Xilinx Zynq platform (A9+FPGA).

This is working so far except there is no std::copysign including cmath. So I have to use copysign without the namespace.

What would be the proper way of adding this function to the namespace?

PS: I do not want to manage the same files on different platforms by hand just for namespace incompatibilities.

Compile flag is:

```
-c -fmessage-length=0 -MT"$@" -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -std=c++11
```

Comment: What compiler options did you use with g++? Are you sure C++11 was enabled?

Comment: I am using the Xilinx sdk (2016.3) which is some kind of Eclipse based.
I am using the flags "-c -fmessage-length=0 -MT"$@" -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -std=c++11"

Comment: Can you post the full error when you build your code?

Comment: And can you check your gcc version and your environment, I found [this bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/231713) and [this](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00247.html)

Comment: @wasthishelpful: "../src/QRDecomposition.cpp:27:14: error: 'copysign' is not a member of 'std'
s = -1 * std::copysign(s, R.at(n*i + i));"


Danh: gcc version is 5.2.1 (I can confirm on gentoo with gcc-4.9.3 this bug does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a macro for msvc.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) 
#define copysign std::copysign
#endif
```

However, c++11 should have the std namespace. If you aren't compiling with c++11 enabled you might be getting a older set of libraries maybe? I'd check to make sure that you are. If you can't compile with c++11 on your platform then the above should work. Add more preprocessor flags to target more platforms if needed.

Another option is

```
using namespace std;
```

which would cover both cases.

Comment: I am compiling with c++11 auto and some other functions are working like expected.

Also the problem is not MSVC, the problem is the arm gcc used in Xilinx SDK.

Comment: You could also put 'using namespace std;' there and that would cover both options.